# If condiction with two different values for same variable

Tags: c#

I have to allow upload of two different types of image dimension
image can either be of width 370 or 602

How can I check it using if image width `370 or 602` with if statement.

If image width are correct then it is okay otherwise I delete the file.

Below code always fails even as either if dimension doesn't match. How can I make below to allow either dimension?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        int imgW = 370; // assuming image width is 370

        if (imgW != 370 || imgW != 602)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("One");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Two");
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (imgW == 370 || imgW == 602)`? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Change OR (||) to AND (&&). So, you will have if the image's width is not 370 AND not 602. Code should be like this: `if (imgW != 370 && imgW != 602)`. This is the same as `if (!(imgW == 370 || imgW == 602))` or  `if (imgW == 370 || imgW == 602)` but with switched bodies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a collection of allowed widths to make the code more readable and extendable:

```
var allowedWidths = new[]{ 370, 602 };
if(allowedWidths.Contains(imgW))
{
    // upload
}
else
{
    // delete
}
```

with single value comparisons:

```
if(imgW == 370 || imgW == 602)
{
    // upload
}
else
{
    // delete
}
```

Comment: Second option is fine as width can be only of two different dimension

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have mentioned:

> How can I check it using if image width 370 or 602 with if statement.

What you need is the `==` operator to allow either dimension as you wanted:

```
if (imgW == 370 || imgW == 602)
```